# go slice not behaving as expected

Tags: go

I was trying to get hands-on in slice and I observed that its not behaving as expected.

I was trying to get the cartesian product of n arrays of diff size. The output is not correct.

here is my code

```
func main() {
   sl1 := []int{1,2,3}
   sl2 := []int{4}
   sl3 := []int{5,6}
   sl4 := []int{8,9}
   sl := [][]int{sl1,sl2,sl3,sl4}
   res := cartesianMain(sl)
   fmt.Println(res)
}

func cartesianMain(a [][]int)  [][]int {
   res := [][]int{}
   for i:=0;i<len(a[0]) ;i++{
       res = append(res,[]int{a[0][i]})
   }
   for i:= 1;i<len(a) ;i++{
       res = cartesianProduct(res,a[i])
   }
   return res;
}
func cartesianProduct(a [][]int, b []int) [][]int {
   result := [][]int{}
   for _,v1 := range b {
       for _,v2 := range a {
           result = append(result, append(v2,v1))
       }
   }
return result
}
```

actual output:

```
[[1 4 5 9] [2 4 5 9] [3 4 5 9] [1 4 6 9] [2 4 6 9] [3 4 6 9] [1 4 5 9] [2 4 5 9] [3 4 5 9] [1 4 6 9] [2 4 6 9] [3 4 6 9]]
```

expected output:
if you see the sl4's 1st element 8 is over written by 9.
correct answer will be :

```
[[1 4 5 8] [2 4 5 8] [3 4 5 8] [1 4 6 8] [2 4 6 8] [3 4 6 8] [1 4 5 9] [2 4 5 9] [3 4 5 9] [1 4 6 9] [2 4 6 9] [3 4 6 9]]
```

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Comment: Read the two official blog post which describe how slices work.

Comment: why do you think that the output is not correct, Please explain

Comment: hi @cslrnr I have modified the qstsn with the correct answer. actually 8 is overwritten with 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is becuase of how `append` works. In Go, slice is a header that keeps 3 property: `Len`, `Cap`, and `Ptr`. `Len` is the length of the slice it self, `Cap` is the capacity of the undrlying array of the slice (the memory), and `Ptr` is the pointer to the array.

When `append` appends to a slice where there are no more space in the underlying array, it allocates a new underlying array with some more space than needed and copies the content of the orignal slice into it and then adds the new element.

And When `append` appends to a slice where `Cap` > `Len`, i.e. where there are still sufficent space in the already allocated memory, `append` keeps the underlying array and copies the element to add to the `a[Len+1]` (where a is the underlying array).  This will cause problem when two or more slice share the underlying memory.

A rule of thumb is to frequently check the need of copying a slice to avoid undesired sharing of underlying array.

To fix the problem, change `result = append(result, append(v2,v1))` to `result = append(result, append([]int{}, append(v2, v1)...))`.

See also: https://blog.golang.org/slices

Note 1: `append([]int{},append(v2,v1...))` is a shortcut of `copy` and `apply`. More tricks for slice can be found at: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks .

Note 2: In Go, nil is a valid value for slice. so you can get rid of the seperation of split in `cartesianMain` by setting `res` to `[]int{nil}`.

Note 3: For better performance and less allocations, it is a good practise to set the capacity (or length) for known slice. In `cartesianProduct`, you can use `result := make([][]int, 0, len(a)*len(b))`.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rLqDGWoTLKS

Comment: Thank you @leaf bebop. I got the trick.

Comment: and also thank you for these useful links ...